# Use IP Address to access another machine on local network but inside VPN

Tags: vpn, ip-address

Here's my scenario.

Within my Comcast home network, there are two devices, A and B.

A is logged into a corporate VPN through cisco anyconnect.

However, from B's point of view, A's ip address doesn't seem to change when do `arp -a`.

And B can still access A thru its ip address.

1,Then B can also access intranet resources thru A. Isn't it?

2, How does the communication between A and B happen? Does it go over the local router? Or does it go thru the VPN's proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short and easy answer is no.

Why is that? Most Company VPNs are configured that the VPN Client locks your local PC to the VPN exclusivly. This is done for security reasons.

In some cases the VPN Client allows you to use the local Internet Access for browsing, because routing all the traffic via VPN to the Internet is very slow. But it depends on the configuration of your companys VPN if this is possible.

If the VPN Client does allow you local Internet Access it would be possible to route the traffic from B to VPN via A. To do so you have to set up A to act as a router beetween ist VPN and the local Network. This is a very complicated Setup and I would not recommend to use it.

Cisco Routers with VPN capability allow you to Setup a permant Connection beetween your local LAN and the remote Network. This is much more easy and usually used to connect some remote Office to the main Company Network. But this also needs Special configuration on the company VPN.

If you Need VPN Access on B the easyest way to do so is to use the VPN Client on B too.

Comment: How does the communication between A and B happen? Why B is able to access A from its local IP address? Aren't A and B separated by VPN?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, "B" won't be able to access the intranet because "A" won't work as a bridge between the two networks (local and intranet); [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) (from "B" to "A") or [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) will probably work though.
2. Even though "A" is hooked up to another network using Anyconnect, its locally assigned IP address will remain unchanged and therefore communicate with the rest of your home network. Your router does the traffic switching from "A" to "B" and vice versa.